# I have this SQL query working and I want to migrate to the Laravel Query Builder format

Tags: php, laravel

Today is working with this SQL Query.

```
 SELECT me.id
 FROM refrees r
 LEFT JOIN matches m
 ON m.refree_id = r.id
 LEFT JOIN match_events me
 ON m.id = me.match_id
 WHERE  r.id = 1
 AND me.match_event_type_id = 2
```

I have tried it, but its not working.

```
 $c = DB::table('refrees as r')
 ->leftJoin('matches as m', 'r.id', '=', 'm.refree_id')
 ->leftJoin('match_events as me', 'me.id', '=', 'm.id')
 ->where('r.id', '=', '1')
 ->where('me.match_event_type_id', '=', '2')
 ->select('me.id')
 ->get();
```

Comment: We need a little more than "not working".

Comment: Please, add the Query error in your question. If there is no error just convert it to array and echo it:  print_r($c->toArray())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. It was

```
 ->leftJoin('match_events as me', 'me.id', '=', 'm.id')
```

where I would put

```
 ->leftJoin('match_events as me', 'me.id_match', '=', 'm.id')
```

Comment: Those two lines are the same.

Answer (score 2):

The is a different condition in your second join.

```
LEFT JOIN match_events me m.id = me.match_id
```

have to be

```
->leftJoin('match_events as me', 'me.match_id', '=', 'm.id')
```

and not

```
->leftJoin('match_events as me', 'me.id', '=', 'm.id')
```

Comment: My bad. It was  
        ->leftJoin('match_events as me', 'me.id', '=', 'm.id')
 where I would put 
       ->leftJoin('match_events as me', 'me.id', '=', 'm.id')